# Child Component is not updating when data inside object is changed

Tags: angular, routes, nested-routes

I have AppComponent on which I have defined routing.
In that, I have a setting like `Home/Scan/:name` where I have multiple names which call different GET service which accepts name as a parameter.

I have defined `[routerLink]="['Scanning',r.name]"` as a link. My child component is not getting refreshed with new data. Please tell what I am doing wrong.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'Home', component: ReportComponent,children:[
{ path: 'Scanning', component: ScanningOutputComponent},
{ path: 'Scanning/:name',component: ScanningOutputComponent }
 ]},
{ path: '',redirectTo:'Home', pathMatch:'full' },
{ path: '**',redirectTo:'Home', pathMatch:'full' }
];
```

Updated code.

Receiving Params from ReportComponent for below code.

```
  this.aRoute.params.subscribe(params => this.sub = params['name']);
switch (this.sub) {
  case 'All':
    this.http.get('http://192.168.117.107:8080/rest/ScanningOutput/all')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.scanningdata = data;
        //console.log(data);
      });
    break;
  case 'POD':
    this.http.get('http://192.168.117.107:8080/rest/ScanningOutput/ByDevice/POD')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.scanningdata = data;
        //console.log(data);
      });
    break;
  case 'PUP':
    this.http.get('http://192.168.117.107:8080/rest/ScanningOutput/ByDevice/PUP')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.scanningdata = data;
        //console.log(data);
      });
    break;
  case 'REX':
    this.http.get('http://192.168.117.107:8080/rest/ScanningOutput/ByDevice/REX')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.scanningdata = data;
        //console.log(data);
      });
    break;
  default:
    console.log("invalid");
    break;
}
```

Comment: routes should be an array

Comment: updated my code. please suggest on updated code.

Comment: Routing works when I call routerLink at first, but when I pass other values and get data from GET API my view does not get refreshed with new data

Comment: The switch is outside of this.aRoute.params.subscribe.
It will not run on every update of this.sub

Answer (score 1):

You have wrote `scanning` where you have defined routes,and you are passing  `scan` in routerlink

Comment: Routing works when I call routerLink at first, but when I pass other values and get data from GET API my view does not get refreshed with new data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the switch inside the subscribe section:

```
this.aRoute.params.subscribe(params => { 
        this.sub = params['name'];
        switch (this.sub) {
            case 'All':
                this.http.get('http://192.168.117.107:8080/rest/ScanningOutput/all')
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        this.scanningdata = data;
                        //console.log(data);
                    });
                break;
            ...
            default:
                console.log("invalid");
                break;
        }
    });
```